# Rails + Google maps, show multiple marker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I need to show the position of an user inside my Rails application, I used the following code and it works well:

```
function showLocations(){
    <% if @profile.location.latitude.nil? || @profile.location.longitude.nil? %>

   canvas = $('#map_canvas');
   canvas.html("<h1>The user have not specified his location yet</h1>")
   canvas.slideDown();

<%else%>
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(<%=@profile.location.latitude%>, <%=@profile.location.longitude%>);
var myOptions = {
  zoom: 12,
  center: latlng,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
var canvas = document.getElementById("map_canvas")
var map = new google.maps.Map(canvas,
myOptions);

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: latlng,
  title:"<%=@profile.full_name%>"
  });

  marker.setMap(map);



  <%end%>

  $('#map_canvas').slideDown('slow');

}
```

Now, I want to take an Array of users and show mutiple marker on the map, so suppose that I no longer have @profile but @profile_array, and each of them have to be represented by a marker on the map. How do you think could I change the code above in order to achieve what I want ?
Tnx

Comment: why don't you use my gem `gmaps4rails` ?